# Glassfish dynamic application reloading not working

Tags: configuration, glassfish-3

I'm running Glassgfish 3.1.2, and I'd like it to automatically reload the application when I run a build and new class files are copied into the application (in domain1/applications/).

In the Glassfish admin I go to Domain -> Application Configuration, and "Reload" is checked.  "Reload Poll Interval" is set to 2 seconds.

Shouldn't that mean if I copy new class files in, then within 2 seconds, Glassfish will reload the app?  It doesn't seem to be paying attention.  I don't see anything in the logs that shows the app reloaded, and my new class files aren't picked up.  I have confirmed that they are copying out correctly.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing the right thing in Glassfish's config.

You might want to trigger manually the reload by updating a file yourself in the application directory, so you will know if it is the automatic reload that's broken, or the process that copies .class files when you rebuild.

See Oracle's doc for more informations about Dynamic Reloading, there's a section about manually updating the app dir at the bottom of that page.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4337/beadz/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this configuration  on your `web.xml` file:

`<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>`

If `<param-value>` is set to `Production` your application won't refresh until you deploy again.